# PatternSyntaxException при вызове replaceAll()

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Есть участок кода:

```
String[] del = {"\"", "\'", ",", ".", ";", "`", ":", "!", "(", ")", "<", ">", "-", "_"};

for (String delElement : del) {
    word = word.replaceAll(delElement, "");
}
```

При компиляции выкидывает исключение PatternSyntaxException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
(
 ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Pattern.java:1813)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2908)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
at WordCounter.main(WordCounter.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как первым аргументом метод `replaceAll` принимает регулярное выражение, то `(` воспринимается как спец. символ (как [начало группы и т.д.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). Поэтому его нужно экранировать. То же самое касается `)`. А ещё `.` в регулярных выражениях обозначает любой символ, поэтому `.replaceAll(".", "")` приводит к пустой строке в качестве результата.

```
String[] del = { "\"", "\'", ",", "\\.", ";", "`", ":", "!", "\\(", "\\)", "<", ">", "-", "_" };
String word = "abc\"',.;`:!()<>-_def";
for (String delElement : del)
{
    word = word.replaceAll(delElement, "");
}
System.out.println(word);
```

Так как используется рег. выражение, то можно все элементы для исключения объединить в одно выражение, дабы делать всего один `replaceAll`. Однако читабельностью такой вариант не особо отличается:

```
String del = "[\"',\\.;`:!\\(\\)<>\\-_]";
String word = "abc\"',.;`:!()<>-_def";
word = word.replaceAll(del, "");
System.out.println(word);
```

Comment: А почему экранирование двумя слешами, а не одним?

Comment: @Evgeniy запись `\\(` приводит к тому, что по факту в строке будет храниться `\(`. А это в контексте рег. выражений как раз значит "просто символ (".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
String[] del = {"\"", "\'", ",", ".", ";", "`", ":", "!", "(", ")", "<", ">", "-", "_"};

for (String delElement : del) 
        word = word.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(delElement), "");
```